# How to prevent parent constructor from being called?

Tags: delphi, inheritance

I created a new descendant that overloads the base constructor

```
TJSONTOXML = class(TIpwJSON)
            private
               ...
            public
               constructor Create(AOwner: TForm; ALogLevel: Integer); reintroduce; overload;
            end;
```

but I forgot to change the previous create call

```
lIpwJSON := TIpwJSON.Create(Self);
```

to the new

```
lJSONToXML := TJSON2XML.Create(Self,lLevel);
```

Instead I just replaced the type so it was:

```
lJSONToXML := TJSON2XML.Create(Self);
```

It took me quite some time to figure this out ;-(

Is there a way to prevent this?
I could do a dirty `Create(AOwner)` override with an `Assert(False)` but prefer a cleaner way.

Note: parent constructors were

```
public

  constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); overload; override;
  constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent; OEMKey: string); reintroduce; overload;
```

Comment: Why are you using `reintroduce` and `overload`? And how is the parent constructor declared?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Picked that from seeing it in the parent ;-) Question updated.

Comment: Do you understand what `reintroduce` does here?

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1758917/delphi-pascal-overloading-a-constructor-with-a-different-prototype) might be interesting for you to read. Also read the other anwsers, not only the accepted

Comment: Seems like the wrong design.  If you don't want to expose the functionality of the base class then why not use composition instead of inheritance?